# Redis OM Spring - Gradle issue: not generating meta classes "com.redis.om.skeleton.models.Person$

Tags: redis-om-spring

I am trying to use gradle for this project https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/tutorials/stack-spring/. My build.gradle is this one:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
compileOnly {
extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation "com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.6.4"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am getting the following err while build this project:

error: cannot find symbol

import com.redis.om.skeleton.models.Person$;

It seems META model classes are not being generated by gradle. I am using Intellij Community edition with java 17.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following to my build.gradle and it solved my issue:

annotationProcessor("com.redis.om:redis-om-spring:0.6.4")